# Is "power to mass ratio" in fact independent to mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I was trying to find power to mass ratio of sun (work done per second at each unit mass at average), but I found the unit is quite straight:

$ W=kg \space m^2 s^{-3}$

Then $W/kg= m^2 s^{-3}$

Which has no kg in it, is that true? If so, how can I explain it in plain text? (Eg: what is $m^2$ in terms of the sun?)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the unit of mass does not appear is because the units of power are $\text{kg m}^2\text{ s}^{-3}$ and so the power to mass ratio is $\dfrac{\text{kg m}^2 \text{ s}^{-3}}{kg} =\text{m}^2\text{ s}^{-3}$

---

For each type of fusion the number of fusions per second which produce energy depends on the number of atoms capable of undergoing that type of fusion, ie twice as many atoms produce twice as much energy per second.

So for each type of fusion the power $\propto$ number of atoms.
Now if the proportion of different types of fusions stays the same and the total number of atoms capable of fusion as a proportional of the total number of atoms stays the same then the power $\propto$ mass of all atoms which is the mass of the Sun.

So power per unit mass ratio $\propto \frac{\text{mass}}{\text{mass}}$ is independent of mass.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to involve a terribly famous equation: $E = mc^2$.  Power, then, is $P = E/t = mc^2/t$, and finally power to mass is $P/m = mc^2/(mt) = c^2/t$.  And you can see that this has the dimensions you have.

What this means is that the power output of the Sun is the amount of of its mass it is converting to energy each second, times $c^2$.   The power to mass ratio is how much this is as a proportion of its mass, and this obviously does not depend on its mass.

Comment: The way you have defined *E* is actually rest energy. But we know that not all the rest energy of the sun gets out of it momentarily. Right?

Comment: @Benjamin: well, energy and mass are not really different things.  If the Sun (or anything) emits a certain amount of energy then its mass goes down proportionally.  So if I have a clock (a clockwork clock) which is wound up, and I let it run down, then its mass is now a little bit lower (and it will go up again when I wind it).  It has the same number of atoms in it, but some of its mass was the energy of the spring.

Answer (score 0):

**Power** is defined as: 
$$\begin{align}P &= \frac{dW}{dt} \\
 &= F.v \\
 &= ma\cdot v\end{align}$$

So we have $$\frac{P}{m} = a\cdot v$$

It shouldn't be surprising to find that in power to mass ratio, mass is absent, since Power contains a hidden *mass factor*.

In engineering, power to mass is generally given in units like **Watt/ kg**

Comment: But what would be "a" and "v" for the special case of Sun?

Comment: No I meant to show that P will not contain units of mass, not for the physical significance in this problem.